# How to divert all calls to parent class to child class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, superclass, partial-classes

Suppose I have a C# Project that references a dll that contains Class1. From Project1, I want to extend the functionality of Class1 by using a class called Class2 that inherits from Class1, and then I want to use Class2 whenever Class1 is expected (*without modifying the calls to Class1 to point to Class2, this is key*).

Moreoever, I have to add Class1 is an initialization module (in the framework I am using) which is not called explicitly (it's part of the inner mechanism).
This means I can't simply go and replace calls to Class1 by Class2 after making Class2 extend the behaviour of Class1 in my code.

(How) can this be achieved?

Another idea that just crosses my mind is to use partial classes; however, I doubt that it's possible for a full class to be redefined 'later' as a partial class, outside of that dll.

===== Later edit: I came across an article that seems to suggest that is possible and I'm trying to figure out how. See, in this article it has RestrictFileTypes (Class2) inherit from IInitializableModule (Class1) which is in a dll, but it doesn't say how Class2 replaces all calls of Class1 from then on, going forward (http://world.episerver.com/blogs/al-higgs/dates/2012/11/Restricting-the-file-types/). What do you make of it?

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, you want to leave your declarations as `var obj = new Class1()` and have it automatically point to `Class2`... without any kind of casting or anything?

Comment: Yes, I came across an article that seems to suggest that is possible and I'm trying to figure out how as it would be very helpful for me too. See, in this article it has RestrictFileTypes (Class2) inherit from IInitializableModule (Class1) which is in a dll, but it doesn't say how Class2 replaces all calls of Class1 from then on, going forward (http://world.episerver.com/blogs/al-higgs/dates/2012/11/Restricting-the-file-types/).

Comment: Some more context might be helpful. What are Class1 and Class2? What code is using the functionality of Class1, and why does it need to use the behavior of Class2 instead? Perhaps there's an easier solution to your problem than what you have in mind.

Comment: It sounds like you want to commit some hacking. Try to search for `Injections`.

Comment: Tanner, Class2 is a class in a framework; the class is responsible for a bunch of initializations and validations, when the site is launched or when certain dialogue boxes are opened, for example, a dialogue that allows me to save certain types of file. My aim is to allow for more file extensions in that dialogue - for which I have to modify a condition from a Class1 method, that's basically wrapped up in the framework specific dll. That's the context for short. Dmitry, no hacking, just extending framework behaviour for a client.

Comment: If no hacking and you can't Rebuild some `Framework` from sources. The only way is that the `Framework` has some special mechanism to extend it with your class. So If you're sure that it is possible (there are that way) you should ask question regarding particular `Framework` and examine documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the second requirement ("Moreoever..."). As for the first, I see 2 ways.

You could write class2 and then swap the names of class1 and class2 by manual editing. The occurences should be few, just the cs file names and the constructors. It may be save to use an intermediate name first like you would generally do in a swap operation. This would probably be the easiest and cleanest way but you may not have any control over the current class1 and be unable to rename it. So here's the other way.

You write your class2 naming it class1 again from the start but in a different namespace. You will have a class1 descending from another class1 (the old one) in a different namespace. When you are done, put a using directive for your new namespace in every file that references your old class1 and make sure it is the last using line so it will take precedence over the ones above it. This should work if the current class1 is not a member of the same namespace it is referenced from. If the latter were the case, you would have to insert declarations of your new namespace into all the declarations of the existing one:

```
namespace ns.of.old.class1
{
    namespace ns.of.new.class1
    {
        [...]
        Some reference to / use of class1
    }
}
```

The using directive trick is fragile, someone may notice the directives are not in alphabetic order and right-click them, choosing "Remove and Sort". Your code may then be broken or worse: still compile but using the old class1 again.

Answer (score 1):

This I called *polymorphism* and is implemented through inheritance as illustrated here:

```
using System;

namespace polymorphismExample {
    public class class1 {
        public virtual string A => "I am Class1.A";
        public         string B => "I am Class1.B";
    }
    public class class2 : class1 {
        public override string A => "I am Class2.A";
    //    public override string B => "I am Class1.B";
        public    new   string B => "I am Class2.B";
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            class1 a1_1 = new class1();

            class1 b1_2 = new class2();
            class2 b2_2 = new class2();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "a1_1.A", a1_1.A);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "a1_1.A", a1_1.B);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "b1_2.A", b1_2.A);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "b1_2.A", b1_2.B);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "b2_2.A", b2_2.A);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", "b2_2.A", b2_2.B);
            Console.WriteLine();   
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

which yields as output:

```
a1_1.A: I am Class1.A  
a1_1.A: I am Class1.B

b1_2.A: I am Class2.A  
b1_2.A: I am Class1.B

b2_2.A: I am Class2.A  
b2_2.A: I am Class2.B
```

Note that the commented line in `class2` is so because it cannot compile; as method B is not virtual in `class1`. This pattern requires that `class1` NOT be  a *sealed* class, and that only methods in `class1` marked as being *virtual* (or of course *abstract*) will exhibit the desired behaviour: having the `class2` behaviour invoked even when called on a variable declared as being of type `class1`.

Of course, at all times, the variables must be initialized using a `class2` constructor.